# Null values handling in big scale applications

Tags: null, defensive-programming

Tl;dr: Should we return null and not know origins of the error or throw exceptions and handle them appropriately?

A few years ago I found this article: http://stackify.com/golden-rule-programming/

It says:

```
If it can be null, it will be null
```

This kind of thinking leads to defensive programming throughout the application, tons of `ifnulls` everywhere and in theory SHOULD never get a `NullReferenceException` and be more efficient compared to throwing exceptions everywhere if **null** is encountered.

On the other hand, if we return **null** in all layers of the application, we cannot know for sure where did the **null** value originate from.

The opposite is when throwing exceptions, because we can know origin of the error for sure.

Returning **null** value everywhere can come from data layer, from the database, it can even be business logic trying to make sense of data and failing to do so... Basically, it can be anything.

Therefore, I see two (or three) camps:

1. If it can be **null**, it should be **null**
2. Throw exceptions everywhere, if you encounter **null** value, where it is not anticipated
3. Mix the first two

Forehand, I think `3. Mixing the first two` leads to a less predictable system and therefore slower pace of development, which is not something we want, right?

Using the `1.` one leads to not knowing where did the null came from, but it is more efficient way to handle a big load (billions of requests).

The `2.` is not as efficient performance wise, but is more verbose when diagnosing errors, by just looking at the logs or debugging.

The question itself is really conceptual and the answer I would like to get would be based on experience working with big scale applications. Really looking forward to what you think :)

Comment: NULL isn't always an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing several other options. For example, you could use a language which doesn't have `null`. Haskell, Ruby, Smalltalk, many others simply don't have null references, so the problem doesn't even arise.

Another option would be to use a language which *does* have `null` but has explicit `null` tracking that allows you to statically ensure that you can never have null references. Spec# does that, for example.

A variant of that option is to use a language which doesn't have `null` tracking, but use an external static analyzer, maybe aided by annotations. Code Contracts.NET (an offshoot of Spec#) does that, for example.

Yet another option is to encapsulate the notion of `null`ness into a type. One of the problems with null references is that null references are really overloaded. What does getting a `null` mean? Some things are *meant* to fail, e.g. parsers, or looking up a key in a dictionary. It is normal for parsers to be handed invalid input, it is normal to not find a key in a dictionary, that's not an error, and not an exceptional situation.

For this latter case, you can use an `Option` type. An `Option` is basically kind-of like a collection that is either empty or has exactly one element. (This analogy is actually pretty profound as we shall see shortly.) In the case of the dictionary example, a `Dictionary<K, V>` would have a method `Option<V> get(K key)` which returns either a "filled" `Option` with the value, if the key exists, or an "empty" `Option` if the key doesn't exist. The important thing is that the type system can ensure that you have to deal with both cases in your code.

Except that you often actually *don't* have to deal with both cases. That's where the analogy to collections comes in: an `Option` is isomorphic to a list / an array / an iterator / a stream / an `IEnumerable` / some other kind of collection which is either empty or holds exactly one value. This means that `Option` can implement whatever collections interfaces your language has, can be a member of the collections framework and can be used with all the collections methods. For example, if you want to transform the value, then you don't need to actually get the value out of the `Option`. All collections frameworks have a method to apply a transformation function to every element of the collection (`map` in most languages, `collect` in Smalltalk, Objective-C and Ruby, `select` in SQL and .NET, `transform` in C++). What does `map` do when you call it on an empty collection? It returns an empty collection. And on a non-empty collection it will return another collection with each element (or in this case the only element) transformed. You don't even have to check whether or not your `Option` is empty, you can just call `map` on it, and it will do the right thing.

You can chain multiple `map`s. You can use `flatMap` (`SelectMany` in .NET) to chain the use of `Option`s. You can use `fold` (aka `reduce`, `aggregate`, `accumulate`) to get the value out or alternatively supply a default. And so on.

Apart from being a collection, `Option` is also a *monad*, this makes it easy to work with in languages that have special syntactic support for monadic operations (e.g. Haskell's `do`-notation, Scala's `for`-comprehensions, C#'s and VB.NET's LINQ query comprehensions).

In Haskell, it is called `Maybe a` and has two data constructors called `Just a` and `Nothing`. (If you are a Java person read `Maybe<T>` and `Just<T>` and think of data constructors as final subclasses.) In Scala, it is called `Option[T]` and has two subclasses `Some[T]` and `None`. Even Java has one, it is called `Optional<T>`.

Obviously, there is a difference between a language like Haskell, which doesn't have `null` in the first place, and a language like Java, where `Optional<T>` is an afterthought. In the first case, `null`s cannot happen, period. In the second case, I would treat `null` like any other kind of invalid data: intercept it at the outer boundary of your system, and either throw an exception or sanitize it into an `Optional<T>`. (The really nasty thing about a language like Java is of course that a field of type `Optional<T>` may itself be `null`.)

In Scala, for example, `null` mainly exists for compatibility reasons. Pretty much the only way that you can end up with a `null` from the Scala language, is with a declared but not initialized mutable field. However, mutable fields are rarely used in Scala, and very un-idiomatic. No method in the Scala library will ever return `null`. Idiomatic Scala code will never return `null`. Usually, the only way to end up with `null` is by calling Java code, and that is typically handled the way I described above: you have a Scala wrapper for the Java code which handles all potential `null`s and the rest of the code uses that Scala abstraction and doesn't bother with `null` at all.

Yet another option that is however not applicable in all cases is to use a special "empty" object to denote the absence of data instead of `null`. A dummy user account for a `User` field, an empty string for a `String` field, an empty list for a `List` field and so on.

Comment: Really appreciate a long and extensive answer. One thing I would not agree with is the last proposal of empty object usage, because it is way easier to check any other scenario, whether it'd be null, option, maybe, etc.

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing stuff.

> If it can be null, it will be null

That means that any value/object that can be null your code needs to deal with gracefully.

Three camps?  Not know where it came from?  Wrong.

There is one camp:  test for null for any nullable type and deal with it gracefully. If null is not valid you throw an exception and yes you know exactly where the exception came from as the exception has a source.  You don't pass the null on to the next layer if it is not valid and lose where null came from.

At the data layer if null is valid but it means 0 you just assign a 0 to a non-nullable type and be done with it. At the point it is a non-nullable type you no longer need to test null.

Reference types are typically nullable and need to be tested every time.

In most if not all environments value type of decimal cannot be null so you don't need to test for null.

Comment: If null is not valid, then don't even bother checking for it, and let the NullReferenceException happen on its own. Otherwise you'll have tons of code throwing that which the runtime will do for you anyway.

Comment: @whatsisname Right on.  Don't like present a graceful message to the user.  Just crash it on out.

Comment: letting the runtime throw an exception doesn't mean you can't catch it. But a null reference exception is one of those things that's almost always an unexpected error, which is not going to be something the user will be able to do anything about. Furthurmore, since a null reference is an invalid situation the overwhelming majority of the time, all the time spent putting in useless redundant messages is time you can't spend doing things that are actually useful.

Answer (score 0):

One can look at state from three points:

1. The state-space the underlying machine provides.
2. The state-space the language provides.
3. The state-space the program-logic allows.

In "safe" languages, the first one can generally be disregarded. Though it's good for things like boolean values that are neither true nor false.

Haskell for example allows you to restrict most variables state-space to their program-logic space, while many others like Java make just about everything nullable, even if it logically isn't.

Thus you must handle it appropriately for each case.
Luckily, in "safe" languages you don't have to write most `null`-checks manually, the language throws an exception for you if you just use it.